# How to Generate new number each time when value changes

Tags: sql, database

I need to generate a random number based on below three conditions

1. Generate new PRCnumber when color changes
2. Generate new PRCnumber when the day changes
3. Generate new PRCnumber when color remains same but shirt number
   changes within the day.

The random number will be used as identifier for the lot of the products generated. Shirt table will have the shirt number and respective color details.

Below is the query I will be using to fetch and it will take shirt number Shirt_num as input

```
 select shirt.facility,
        shirt.color,
        shirt.lotnum,
        colorMgr.untpal,
        colorMgr.style,
        shirt.product_line
   from shirt,
        colorMgr,
        products
  where colorMgr.facility = shirt.facility
    and colorMgr.color = shirt.color
    and colorMgr.color_id = shirt.color_id
    and shirt.product_line = products.product_line
    and shirt.shirtnum = @shirtnum;
```

I want to write conditions something like but not sure how to catch and compare when new color keeps changing.

```
if day_changes ()
     SELECT RAND() as prcnumber
else if shirt_num_changes()
     SELECT RAND() as prcnumber
else if color_changes ()
     SELECT RAND() as prcnumber
..........
```

The desired output will be something like this.

```
shirt_num RandomNum Color Day
1111011   384700412 Black 26 Feb, 2021
1111011   384700132 Black 27 Feb, 2021 (Random numbr when day changes)
1111017   384701792 Black 26 Feb, 2021 (Random numbr when shirt_num changes)
1111011   384700458 Blue  26 Feb, 2021 (Random numbr when color changes)
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the random number? And when is a field considered to have changed? Could you provide an example of your inputs and expected outputs, please?

Comment: Random number will be used as lot number , works as Identifier for all the products generated for every category on a day

Comment: I think I understand, and an example of input rows and your expected output would clarify and help people answer.

Comment: I have tried to explain the desired output with a picture attached. Hopefully it will show the exact requirement

Comment: I see. Your query needs an `order by` to know when something has changed. Perhaps instead make a checksum of the fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with [window functions](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/), but it would depend on the ordering of the query, and it would not be deterministic (you'd get a different number each query).

I would instead recommend using a [checksum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1) of the fields.

```
mysql> select *, sha1(concat_ws('|', shirtnum, color, day)) from shirts;
+----------+-------+------------+--------------------------------------------+
| shirtnum | color | day        | sha1(concat_ws('|', shirtnum, color, day)) |
+----------+-------+------------+--------------------------------------------+
|      111 | black | 2021-02-26 | ad48a0f6b9b197ce11a78a85bca70a487af8f028   |
|      111 | black | 2021-02-26 | ad48a0f6b9b197ce11a78a85bca70a487af8f028   |
|      111 | blue  | 2021-02-26 | d863fb4761e0deae3815b6f1ab53c69d5a1a2958   |
|      222 | black | 2021-02-26 | a5dbace4af2bd0510178dcb05065392f2a73d3c0   |
|      222 | black | 2021-02-27 | 1906c453b7bff2b140bb972be8ba29fa80260392   |
|      222 | black | 2021-02-27 | 1906c453b7bff2b140bb972be8ba29fa80260392   |
|      111 | black | 2021-02-27 | c0061ba0d2be5d261c0f7ddcb28ccd8de0ea7c52   |
+----------+-------+------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

The advantage is this is deterministic and does not depend on the order of the results.

You can implement this as a [generated column](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-generated-columns/) if your database supports that, or with a [view](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_create_view.asp).

```
mysql> create view shirt_ids as select *, sha1(concat_ws('|', shirtnum, color, day)) as whatever_this_is from shirts;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from shirt_ids;
+----------+-------+------------+------------------------------------------+
| shirtnum | color | day        | whatever_this_is                         |
+----------+-------+------------+------------------------------------------+
|      111 | black | 2021-02-26 | ad48a0f6b9b197ce11a78a85bca70a487af8f028 |
|      111 | black | 2021-02-26 | ad48a0f6b9b197ce11a78a85bca70a487af8f028 |
|      111 | blue  | 2021-02-26 | d863fb4761e0deae3815b6f1ab53c69d5a1a2958 |
|      222 | black | 2021-02-26 | a5dbace4af2bd0510178dcb05065392f2a73d3c0 |
|      222 | black | 2021-02-27 | 1906c453b7bff2b140bb972be8ba29fa80260392 |
|      222 | black | 2021-02-27 | 1906c453b7bff2b140bb972be8ba29fa80260392 |
|      111 | black | 2021-02-27 | c0061ba0d2be5d261c0f7ddcb28ccd8de0ea7c52 |
+----------+-------+------------+------------------------------------------+
```